# Stuck outside Italy (will my Permesso di Soggiorno be revoked?)

Tags: resident-permit

I have a Permesso di Soggiorno per motivi familiari (my sister is Italian). My last appointment for the renewal of my Permesso di Soggiorno was on December 12, 2019. My new Permesso di Soggiorno is valid for two years.

From what I know, I can stay outside of Italy for a maximum consecutive period corresponding to half of the length of my permit. This means I can stay outside of Italy for a maximum of 12 months in a row. I left Italy on December 18, 2019. So I should return back to Italy before December 18, 2020, otherwise I will have been outside of Italy for more that 12 months.

According to Italian Covid-19 regulations, passengers from the country I'm in are currently banned from entering Italy, and flights from here to Italy are currently suspended. Hence, I am forced to stay out of Italy for a longer period of time than I’m allowed. However, I am not sure if these regulations apply to me as a legal Italian resident with a valid Permesso di Soggiorno.

Do the rules regarding the period of time allowed to stay outside Italy still apply during the Covid-19 pandemic? Will my Permesso di Soggiorno be revoked if I stay outside Italy for more than 12 months even if I cannot return at the moment?

I'm wondering if someone reading this is in a similar situation and was able to get an answer from an official source like an Italian embassy or official government website.

Comment: The Italian consulate would be the best authority to ask about pandemic exceptions for stays outside of Italy by 3rd country residents. While your residence permit is valid you are allowed to enter the Schengen Area.